# Automatically run Greenify from Macrodroid

Tags: automation, background-process, greenify, macrodroid

As a way to save battery drain, I set up a macro with MacroDroid that does the following:

- Trigger: every 2 hours
- Action: kill background process, launch Greenify
- Constraint: when battery is below 50%

I would like to not only launch Greenify, but also run it and then close automatically. I suppose it is possible to do this within a script, but I absolutely have no idea about this.

Another question is: if I kill background processes, is Greenify redundant?

Relevant information:

- Android version: 8.0
- Phone model: SONY Xperia XZ2 (default launcher)
- Macrodroid version: 3.30.3
- Greenify version: 4.3.3.0

Thank you.